# What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: modeling

Im trying to follow the CGgeek Steve Lund's Blender tutorial on the swinging balls animation at (Youtube.com/watch?v=Uq4OLSRgSQE). When I reach the section on duplicating the first swinging ball I can create and confirm the duplicate, but the duplicate disappears when I attempt to change its orientation and I end up changing the original's orientation instead.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Change the title and add .blend or screenshots of your problem?